# Validation of Facebook Badge in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, facebook

I would like users of my Rails application to be able to submit their [Facebook Badge](http://www.facebook.com/badges/) as input in a form, but I absolutely want to to verify that what they provide is a valid Badge, not something that may compromise the security of my system (Javascript ...).

Is there a good way to validate a form field that contains a Facebook Badge?

Comment: You may want to clarify if you're attempting to validate that it's A badge or if it's a badge with accurate information... In addition, every time FB changes the format of their badges, your site will break - You're probably better off to retrieve the info you want using the FB API

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you could safely develop something that would validate badges.  By "safely" I mean something that wouldn't generate false negatives (or false positives) if/when Facebook happens to change their implementation of badges (as they are wont to do with many parts of their platform).

What you *can* do is use something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to ensure that the input doesn't contain malicious tags.

Comment: Woah, no need to be a vote nazi about it - a simple comment is all it takes.  Updated my link.

Comment: :D Removed my -1 - And you get a +1 for the sense of humour :)

Comment: Thanks Peter for both your suggestions. I will go for using their API